Are there any techniques in getting past Javascript checks with BeautifulSoup?
So I have the following script:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_marketwatch_calendar(url):
    #page=requests.get(url).text
    #soup=BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html5lib')
    print(soup)
    title_parent = soup.find("div", class_="column column --primary")
    print(title_parent)
url = "https://www.marketwatch.com/economy-politics/calendar?mod=economy-politics"
parse_marketwatch_calendar(url)

However, when I run it, I get the following repeated response:
<html><head><title>marketwatch.com</title><style>#cmsg{animation: A
1.5s;}@keyframes A{0%{opacity:0;}99%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}</style></head><body style="margin:0"><p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p><script data-cfasync="false">var dd={'rt':'c','cid':'AHrlqAAAAAMA0byAgFOkDSoAGKNiPA==','hsh':'D428D51E28968797BC27FB9153435D','t':'bv','s':47891,'e':'a873fd745afc33d92e8f68dbadb4eaa3536c2c677a9785033316a437fb980f49','host':'geo.captcha-delivery.com'}</script><script data-cfasync="false" src="https://ct.captcha-delivery.com/c.js"></script></body></html> None

A Javascript checker is intercepting my page and I'm not able to access the MarketWatch Economic Calendar itself. I suppose I can find a different source but without switching to Selenium, is there any way to get to the actual page with requests or urllib? I was thinking of adding a user agent header that's JavaScript enabled but IDK if this would even work or if I'm better off going to Selenium to make the initial website call. Thanks! :)

Puppeteer / Selenium / Mocha / etc

The answer is no. bs4 is just an HTML parser and doesn't have any capabilities to run JS.
